# How do I fix the shading

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
The cloth looks funky. I don't know how to fix that. Help! The more I subdivide the plane, the more I lag so Thats not an option here.

Comment: You may have a duplicate cloth or faces causing Z Fighting. Also, in your SubSurf Modifier the View is set to one and the Render to six. So you are not  previewing what the final render would be. In general 2 or maybe 3 would be adequate.

Comment: @dontwalk That  is the rendered version of it. How do i remove the duplicate?

Comment: If it is a duplicate Object in Object Mode select it and press "X" do delete it. If it has duplicate vertices/faces in Edit Mode try "Remove Doubles" or select one Vertex and press CTRL + L to select Linked Vertices and then press "X".

Comment: Are you using smooth shading?

Comment: Does your 'cloth' mesh have thickness (a separate front and back surface)? Your overlapping geometry could be the result of two layers of cloth intersecting each other. This *could* be resolved by adding self-collision (but that would make the calculations more intensive and might not actually help). Alternatively, ensure your cloth is only a flat plane with no thickness. Also - as already mentioned - use the arrows in the Modifier stack to move the Cloth modifier above the subdivision; this way the cloth works on a simpler mesh and the result is sub-divided rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You just might move cloth simulation over sur-sub modifier.